# Select newly inserted record in JDatabase

Tags: jdatabase

I am manually adding a record using `PHP (sourcerer)` into `Jdatabase`. I wish to select the record that was `added using the insert query` below. Is there a wayout without using another query with where clause to get the same record added by the insert query? Thanks in advance.

> I don't want to get the last row of the table in which the record was
>   inserted.

**Insert query:**

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$columns = array('teacher_id', 'sub_code','active');
$values = array($db->quote($teacher), $db->quote($sub_code),1);
$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__teachers_classes'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$db->insertid();
```

directly after executing. This should give you the last inserted id.